# pan to bake a pound cake

Tags: cake, pan

I have a recipe for pound cake that I love, but I make it in a tube pan.  I would like to make it in a 9x13 oblong pan, but don't know how long the cake should bake or if the recipe I use in the tube pan would fit into the oblong pan.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Will it will fit is an easy one. Go here: http://www.joyofbaking.com/PanSizes.html.
All but the biggest tube pan is less volume than a 9X13X2 pan.

As for how long it will bake- I don't have the ability to compute the exact new bake time; however, the rectangular pan will produce a thinner cake so the baking time will be reduced.

I would put it in for 3/4 the recipe time and then start checking it at 10 minutes intervals.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you wanted to put it in a 9x13, but if you are just looking for 'something more rectangular', I have had really good luck switching from a tube pan to a standard bread pan.  The cooking time actually increased by a few minutes.

It gives me nice 'square' pound cake that I can slice or cut up for other uses.

Comment: By "standard bread pan", I assume you mean a loaf pan?

Comment: @Marti:  Yes, that's correct.